# Best way to audit (Redshift) database table (enumerate fields, get min/max/count distinct/number of nulls)

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-redshift

Is there a semi-automate way or existing function etc to do this on `Redshift (or SQL server):`

```
    select max(field1),min(field1),count(distinct field1),
           count (case when field1 is null then 1 end),
           max(field2),min(field2)....
           max(field3),min(field3)....
    from table
```

I know I can probably use information schema to get all fields (or the fields I need), then use a script language to generate this `SQL`. Just want to ask if anyone has a better solution?

I don't want to write SQL manually if I need to do this for new table say every a few weeks. If I use things such as `SPSS` modeler I can just drag a node to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: In order to find min and max values of integer fields in the particular table you can use either system view SVV_DISKUSAGE or system table STV_BLOCKLIST.